# Angular2: styling component dynamically inserted by the router

Tags: css, angular

Searched for an answer for this and saw people struggling with this but no direct answer, especially with regards to the released 2.x version of Angular.

Suppose you have `app.component.html` with the following code:

```
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

The router dynamically inserts your custom component, say `my-component` and (strangely enough) places that component as a sibling of `router-outlet` element like so:

```
<div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

Obviously, the router can place another component in there, so you can't rely on the name being `my-component` when creating styles in your `app.component.css` file.

So... How do you do this?

**Why this matters?** Why not just set the styles on the `:host` inside of the `my-component` CSS? Well, because not all styles belong there. For example, if the app.component decides that it's a flex container (i.e., `display: flex;`), that would mean that the `my-component` element should be styled as a flex item (i.e., `flex: 1 0 0;`). Placing the flex item style inside of the `my-component` seems like a bad practice because you are coupling it with the style of its parent component.

Chime in if you know the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: I've attempted something similar without luck, the closest solution was to have the parent push the necessary data to a service and have the child observe it to update it's host data. Clearly not ideal, but as far as I know it's not possible to pass data from the parent through the router-outlet to the child component.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but I guess the adjacent sibling selector should allow you to do that

```
:host div + * {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Placing this CSS into the app.component would have :host refer to the app component's host, not the `my-component`. Placing it inside of the `my-component` doesn't make sense. Not sure what you mean here.

Answer (score 0):

The key is [/deep/](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#-deep-) keyword:

[image]

the style will apply to whatever element followed by router-outlet.

[image]

Or make it specific to apply different style to known components.

```
:host /deep/ router-outlet + my-component {
    display: block;
    border: 10px solid black;
}

:host /deep/ router-outlet + my-component2 {
    display: block;
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```